# Commutators and coordinate-induced basis (General Relativity)

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, commutator, vector-fields

There is an exercise in MTW that asks to prove that, given two vector fields **u** and **v**, there exists a coordinate system for which
$$
\textbf{u}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} \mbox{ and }\textbf{v}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}
$$
if and only if **u** and **v** are linearly independent and commute.

Now, I know that given those vectors defined above, it's easy to show that they commute and are linearly independent, but I'm stuck at showing the other way around: given two vectors that commute and are linearly independent, we can write them like that. I appreciate if anyone could give me some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that this is an exercise problem from MTW (Exercise 9.9), I am trying to find a simpler solution without invoking advanced general results. Here is my take on this,

Given that $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ are vector fields, at any arbitrarily chosen point $\mathcal{P}_0$ they can be written as,
$$\textbf{u}=u^\alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial {y^\alpha} }$$ and $$ \textbf{v}=v^\alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial {y^\alpha} } $$
where, $\frac{\partial}{\partial {y^\alpha}}$ is some coordinate basis for the tangent space at $\mathcal{P}_0$

Since $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ are elements of the tangent space at $\mathcal{P}_0$, they are differential operator themselves. We can write,
$$\frac{d}{d{\lambda}} = u^\alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial {y^\alpha}} = \textbf{u}  $$
where,
$$
\frac{d{y^\alpha}}{d \lambda } = u^\alpha
$$
and similarly,
$$\frac{d}{d {\xi}} = v^\alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial {y^\alpha}} = \textbf{v}$$
where,
$$
\frac{d{y^\alpha}}{d \xi } = v^\alpha
$$

To solve the problem we have to show that there exists a coordinate basis $\frac{\partial}{\partial {x^\alpha}}$ with
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial {x^1}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial {\lambda}} = \textbf{u} $$
and, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial {x^2}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial {\xi}} = \textbf{v} $$
given that the two fields $\textbf{u}, \textbf{v}$ commute and are linearly independent.

Now we have,
$$[\textbf{u},\textbf{v}] = 0,$$
that is,
$$[ \frac{d}{d {\lambda}}, v^\alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial {y^\alpha}}  ] = 0,$$
implying,
$$ \frac{d v^\alpha}{d {\lambda}} \frac{\partial}{\partial {y^\alpha}} = 0, $$
therefore,
$$\frac{d v^\alpha}{d {\lambda}} = 0.$$
We can conclude that in a sufficiently small neighborhood of $\mathcal{P}_0$ the change of parameter $\lambda$ does not affect $\textbf{v}$.

Similarly,
$$\frac{d u^\alpha}{d {\xi}} = 0.$$
and change of $\xi$ does not affect $\textbf{u}$

Therefore, $\lambda$ and $\xi$ can be used as coordinate parameters, with $\frac{\partial}{\partial {\lambda}}$, and $\frac{\partial}{\partial {\xi}}$ as the respective coordinate basis vectors (because they are orthogonal). One can fill out the remaining basis vectors for the tangent space at $\mathcal{P}_0$ to build the required coordinate basis $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}$.

Answer (score 1):

If the vectors form a basis then it is fairly easy to use Poincaré's lemma to show it, namely if $e_1,...,e_n$ is a frame, and $\theta^1,...,\theta^n$ is its dual frame, and the direct frame satisfies the commutation relations $$ [e_a,e_b]=C^c_{\ ab}e_c, $$ then it is easy to show that the dual frame satisfies the differential relations $$ \mathrm d\theta ^a=-\frac{1}{2}C^a_{\ bc}\theta^b\wedge\theta^c=-\sum_{b<c}C^a_{\ bc}\theta^b\wedge \theta^c. $$

If the frame commutes, i.e. $C^c_{\ ab}=0$, then we have $$ \mathrm d\theta^a=0, $$ thus by Poincaré's lemma, each point in the frame's domain of definition has an open neighborhood $\mathscr U$ on which functions $u^1,...,u^n$ exist such that $$ \theta^a=\mathrm du^a . $$

From this point, it is rather easy to see that the $u^1,...,u^n$ form a local coordinate system and that $$ e_a=\frac{\partial}{\partial u^a}. $$

---

If the $e_1,...,e_n$ do not form a frame (but are linearly independent, its just there are not enough of them to be a frame), the proof is more difficult. I am going to skip the details but this can be found in for example Lee's *Introduction to smooth manifolds* (called "canonical form for commuting vector fields" there).

The proof itself is based on the flowout/flow box/straightening theorem. Basically, we know that if $X$ is a vector field that does not vanish in the neighborhood of a point $x$, then there exists a coordinate system $x^1,...,x^n$ such that $$ X=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}. $$

The sketch of the proof is that we can take a hypersurface $\Sigma$ to which $X$ is transversal (not tangential), and we may put a coordinate system $x^2,...,x^n$ on the hypersurface, then use the flow $\phi^X(t,x)$ of the vector field to construct a local foliation of hypersurfaces for which $t=x^1$ labels the individual hypersurfaces and $x^2,...,x^n$ labels a point on the $x^1$ hypersurface. Points with different $x^1$ but same $x^2,...,x^n$ lie on the same integral curve of $X$.

If one has $e_1,...,e_m$ commuting vector fields in the $n$ dimensional manifold $M$, then the basic idea of the proof is quite similar, take an $n-m$ dimensional submanifold to which the $e_1,...,e_m$ are all transversal, put a coordinate system $x^{m+1},...,x^n$ on the submanifold, define $$ \phi_{x^1,...,x^m}(x)=\phi^{e_1}_{x^1}\circ...\circ\phi^{e_m}_{x^m}(x), $$ where $\phi^{e_i}_{x^i}$ is the flow of $e_i$ for time $x^i$.

The fact that the flows of the individual vector fields commute means that $$ \phi_{x^1,...x^i,...,x^j,...,x^m}=\phi_{x^1,...,x^j,...,x^i,...,x^m}, $$ which is crucial in proving that we actually have $$ e_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} $$ once the construction is finished.

Comment: How do you obtain the differential relations of the dual frame?

Comment: Are these relations related to the ones on Chapter 2 Problem 4b) of Wald’s book “General relativity”, to wit $$\frac{\partial(Y^{\gamma*})_\mu}{\partial x^\nu} -\frac{\partial(Y^{\gamma*})_\nu}{\partial x^\mu}= C^\gamma_{\alpha\beta} (Y^{\alpha*})_\mu (Y^{\beta*})_\nu$$? I’m having trouble deriving these.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4872369/show-that-if-e-a-e-b-cc-abe-c-d-thetaa-frac12ca-bc-thetab-w/4872591#4872591